# JavaFx issues with external monitor

Tags: user-interface, javafx, scaling

Running JavaFx on MacOs with external monitor (1920x1200) the fonts is blurry. See the text in the menu.

On Linux Mint with external 4K monitor JavaFx does not scale at all.

Do you know any parameters which can control this ? [image]

Comment: Is it possible that you are hit by this bug on the Mac? https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8236689

Comment: Yes, this happen on Mac.